# Ionic cordova run android Unable to start the daemon process

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, gradle

I need some help. I have an ionic 3 project and until today I can exectute ionic cordova run android without problems. 
Today I have a that I can't solve.

> cordova run android
>   Preparing Firebase on Android
>   ANDROID_HOME=/home/joseproman/Android/Sdk
>   JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64
>   Starting a Gradle Daemon (subsequent builds will be faster)

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Unable to start the daemon process.
  This problem might be caused by incorrect configuration of the daemon.
  For example, an unrecognized jvm option is used.
  Please refer to the user guide chapter on the daemon at https://docs.gradle.org/4.4.1/userguide/gradle_daemon.html

  ### Please read the following process output to find out more:

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError (no error message)
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
  (node:13119) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: /usr/share/gradle/bin/gradle: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
  FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
- What went wrong:
  Unable to start the daemon process.
  This problem might be caused by incorrect configuration of the daemon.
  For example, an unrecognized jvm option is used.
  Please refer to the user guide chapter on the daemon at https://docs.gradle.org/4.4.1/userguide/gradle_daemon.html

  ### Please read the following process output to find out more:

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError (no error message)
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
  at ChildProcess.whenDone (/home/joseproman/Aplicaciones/wata/third.io.marketpay.watafan/platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/cordova-common/src/superspawn.js:169:23)
  at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
  at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:214:7)
  at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:925:16)
  at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:209:5)
  (node:13119) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
  (node:13119) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

Ionic info:
Ionic:

ionic (Ionic CLI)  : 4.0.2 (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic)
   Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.7.0
   @ionic/app-scripts : 3.0.0

Cordova:

cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.0.0
   Cordova Platforms     : android 6.3.0, browser 5.0.3
   Cordova Plugins       : no whitelisted plugins (14 plugins total)

System:

Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1 (/home/joseproman/Android/Sdk)
   NodeJS            : v8.11.2 (/usr/bin/node)
   npm               : 5.8.0
   OS                : Linux 4.18